# It can be deleted a git ssh private key?

Tags: git, ssh, command, private-key

I set my git configuration a year ago since that time I haven't used it.
Now that I need to use it I've forgotten the private ssh key.
I have tried by deleting git but the config still stay somewhere in my computer  when I re-install git.
I need to clone a repository but I can't because, git still requesting the key.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you never used the key before there is no problem to remove it. You will need to create another one to use while trying to communicate with sites light [Github](http://github.com) or trying to clone from a `ssh` repository server.

Also, if you are using git on Linux the key might be stored on `.ssh/` directory inside your home. Even if you remove git, the config file will still be in your home directory too (`.gitconfig`).